# Extract numbers with a regex and grep

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

i have a file which contain:

```
abc:12345
def:56323
```

i want to extract number by grep :

```
grep -o "[0-9]"
```

but it could not give the result :

```
12345
56323
```

Thanks for anyhelp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you missed `[0-9]*`:

```
$ grep -o "[0-9]*" file
12345
56323
```

Note that for this particular case, you can also make use of other tools:

```
while IFS=: read text number
do
  echo "$number"
done < file
```

Or `cut`, `sed` or `awk`:

```
cut -d: -f2 file

sed 's/^[^:]*://' file

awk -F: '{print $2}' file
```

Comment: I will when i have enough 15 reputation ,can you give me one

Comment: Errr to accept you do not need any minimum reputation, it is just to upvote :) But I think now you can